# PHP LDAP Get Members of a group

Tags: php, ldap

Is it possible to get just the members of a LDAP group in PHP?

I've searched google a bit but only found complicated solutions. i just need the name and nothing more.

```
$dn = "o=my_company, c=CH";
$filter="(|(sn=$person*)(vorname=$person*))";
$justthese = array( "ou", "sn", "vorname", "mail");
```

The users are listed in the group with the UID

I've found something like this but can't get anywhere with this.
Hope you can help me and if you need more information tell me please

Comment: This can depend significantly on your LDAP schema. Does the group contain members or does each person have a `memberOf` attribute?

Comment: The group has member and the users dont have `memberOf` attributes

Comment: Are the members listed with their `uid`, `dn`, `mail` or something else? Also, is this a standard schema from somewhere or custom?

Comment: @yakatz with the uid, so i guess it's not possible to get just the name with one query right?

Comment: Correct. There is now enough information to right this up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the additional information in the comments, you can't do this in a single LDAP query.

This is an outline of a possible solution - I used something like it for a LDAP mailing-list manager that I wrote. (This is PHP 7 syntax.)

```php
// Setup and run LDAP Search
$dn = "cn=groups,o=my_company,c=CH"; // Location of groups in directory
$attributes = ['members'];
$filter = sprintf("(groupName=%s)", $group_name);

$search = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $attributes);
$results = ldap_get_entries($conn, $search);

// Function to call on each member
$member_func = function($uid)
{
    // This is a helper that will get the user data and return an appropriate object (or string).
    // Implementation is left as an exercise to the user
    return get_user_details($uid);
};

// Need to filter LDAP results for actual values only
$member_data = array_map($member_func, array_filter($results['members'], function($k) { return is_numeric($k); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```